# Trying to deploy files to planet-lab and failing at codeploy stage (permission denied?)

Tags: python, networking, deployment

We've been trying to use planet-lab.
We have nodes on our slice, and we follow the instructions on http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~jbagdis/planetlab/hello_world.pdf

When we get to "./codeploy ...", we get the following:

```
<<generating a script...>>
<<copying the script...>>

<<executing the script...>>
command is /usr/local/bin/ssh -n -T my_user@my_university.ac@machine './temp1 &'
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
planetlab02.ethz.ch: 0 bytes
```

For every slice we ask.
We have made a public key and uploaded it.

Can't figure out the problem...
Will appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you solved it, but here is my idea; after uploading public key, you have to wait about 1 hours to get start to work on PlanetLab. Also some nodes may be down for some time.

By the way I suggest you to use PlMan to deploy and start your application.
http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/networking/cplane/